# Mocking objects without no-argument constructor in C# / .NET

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, constructor, mocking

Is it possible to create a mock from a class that doesn't provide a no-argument constructor and don't pass any arguments to the constructor? Maybe with creating IL dynamically?

The background is that I don't want to define interfaces only for testing. The workaround would be to provide a no-argument constructor for testing.

Comment: Also speaking from a Moq usage for creating Mocks, you'd need to make the methods virtual. Seems like in that case an interface is generally better. Not sure about other Mocking frameworks.

Comment: Ideally interfaces should be used throughout your code; versus the concrete implementations, thus making the comment of "creating interfaces only for testing" a moot point.

Comment: I consider interfaces with only a single implementation as worthless artefacts.

Comment: You'll find that you have to create an interface when testing in c#. As an alternative, you can provide the virtual keyword to methods/properties, but you'll find that interfaces express your design better, and allow for greater decoupling of concrete instances from consumers.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Sure thing. In this example i'll use Moq, a really awesome mocking library.

Example:

```
public class MyObject
{
     public MyObject(object A, object B, object C)
     {
          // Assign your dependencies to whatever
     }
}

Mock<MyObject> mockObject = new Mock<MyObject>();
Mock<MyObject> mockObject = new Mock<MyObject>(null, null, null); // Pass Nulls to specific constructor arguments, or 0 if int, etc
```

In many cases though, I assign Mock objects as the arguments so I can test the dependencies:

```
Mock<Something> x = new Mock<Something>();
MyObject mockObject = new MyObject(x.Object);

x.Setup(d => d.DoSomething()).Returns(new SomethingElse());

etc
```

Comment: Agreed. Moq is awesome. They have a complete how-to reference on one web page.  You can't be that for ease-of-use/learning.

Comment: Does it work when the constructor requires not-null values (with code contracts or exceptions)?

Comment: For example, if you have an integer, you can pass a 0. If it's a string, Null, string.Empty, etc. You can pretty much go with default(T), where T : your parameter type and everything works out fine. If you are making a mock object, methods / properties marked as virtual will never be executed; you can control what they do (via callback) or what they return (via the Return method) on the mock object.

Answer (score 2):

It is wrong to believe that you are providing interfaces only for testing. Interfaces are there to provide abstractions and weaken the coupling between the different layers of your code making them more reusable in different contexts.

This being said the answer will depend on the mocking framework you are using. For example with Rhino Mocks you could have:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string bar)
    { }

    public virtual int SomeMethod()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
var fooMock = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<Foo>("abc");
fooMock.Expect(x => x.SomeMethod()).Return(10);
```

Comment: Depends on your point of view: True, a developper should write interfaces to weaken coupling. False, a QA doesn't want to "improve" functional code only for testing purposes if he can skip that